# CUDA malloc() minimum and typical actual alignment

Tags: memory-management, cuda, malloc, gpgpu, memory-alignment

The [cudaMalloc() documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g37d37965bfb4803b6d4e59ff26856356) says

> The allocated memory is suitably aligned for any kind of variable.

But...

- What affects the *actual* aligment? Compute capability? CUDA driver version? The specific kind of card? The allocation size?
- Can I determine the minimum / typical allocation alignment as a function of these parameters?

Comment: (a) Not documented. (b) No.

Comment: @DmitriBudnikov: It seems to me the allocation quantum is significantly larger than `alignof(long long)`... isn't it?

Comment: @DmitriBudnikov: Sorry, I meant aligned by a larger quantum. I notice quite a few 0's at the lower bits of allocated areas.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14083295/2386951. Also consider @njuffa's comment on that.

Answer (score 1):

**You can *un-safely* assume it's at least `cudaDeviceProp::textureAlignment` 
(i.e. 256 on Fermi, 512 on Kepler, Maxwell).**

@sgarizvi [reports](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14083295/1593077) that, from his experimentation on multiple devices, that the alignment of allocated blocks of device memory is no less than the texture alignment field of the device properties ( `cudaDeviceProp::textureAlignment`). For Kepler and Maxwell devices this is 512 bytes.

Of course, like @talonmies notes, this is not actually guaranteed nor is it documented.