# why does tensorflow allocate more memory than requested in gpu? Is there any function to determine how much the memory allocated?

Tags: memory-management, tensorflow

the following question is not about how to [config  fraction of gpu memory used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199233/how-to-prevent-tensorflow-from-allocating-the-totality-of-a-gpu-memory).

CPU:

> FixedLengthRecordReaderV2 allocation_description { requested_bytes: 64
>   allocated_bytes: 64 allocator_name: "cpu" allocation_id: 107996

GPU:

> Reshape/shape" tensor { dtype: DT_INT32 shape { dim { size: 1 } }
>   allocation_description { requested_bytes: 4 allocated_bytes: 256
>   allocator_name: "cuda_host_bfc" allocation_id: 329 ptr: 1112161657600
>   } } }
>
> "Unknown" tensor { dtype: DT_UINT8 shape { dim { size: 3073 } }
>   allocation_description { requested_bytes: 3073 allocated_bytes: 3328
>   allocator_name: "gpu_bfc" allocation_id: 152161 has_single_reference:
>   true ptr: 1108327235584 } } }
>
> Reshape/shape" tensor { dtype: DT_INT32 shape { dim { size: 1 } }
>   allocation_description { requested_bytes: 4 allocated_bytes: 256
>   allocator_name: "cuda_host_bfc" allocation_id: 329 ptr: 1112161657600
>   } } }
>
> DecodeRaw" tensor { dtype: DT_UINT8 shape { dim { size: 3073 } }
>   allocation_description { requested_bytes: 3073 allocated_bytes: 4864
>   allocator_name: "cuda_host_bfc" allocation_id: 35574
>   has_single_reference: true ptr: 1112190177280 } } }
>
> transpose/perm" tensor { dtype: DT_INT32 shape { dim { size: 3 } }
>   allocation_description { requested_bytes: 12 allocated_bytes: 256
>   allocator_name: "cuda_host_bfc" allocation_id: 331 ptr: 1112161658112
>   } } }
>
> stack" tensor { dtype: DT_INT32 shape { dim { size: 3 } }
>   allocation_description { requested_bytes: 12 allocated_bytes: 256
>   allocator_name: "cuda_host_bfc" allocation_id: 332 ptr: 1112161658368
>   } } }
>
> stack" tensor { dtype: DT_INT32 shape { dim { size: 3 } }
>   allocation_description { requested_bytes: 12 allocated_bytes: 256
>   allocator_name: "cuda_host_bfc" allocation_id: 332 ptr: 1112161658368
>   } } }
>
> stack" tensor { dtype: DT_INT32 shape { dim { size: 3 } }
>   allocation_description { requested_bytes: 12 allocated_bytes: 256
>   allocator_name: "cuda_host_bfc" allocation_id: 332 ptr: 1112161658368
>   } } }

1.Why does tensorflow allocate more memory than requested in gpu?

2.Is there any function to determine how much the memory allocated?

For the first question, I guest the purpose is that it can reduce the frequence of allocation. But I cannot understand why this mechanism is adopted by gpu while cpu  memory allocator does not.

I am more interested in the second question.

Does anyone know the answer? Any information will be helpful.

Comment: not duplicate (-:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably due to memory [alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14082964/cuda-alignment-256bytes-seriously).
So you cannot get chunks of memory that are smaller than 256 bytes and if you want more it always will be multiples of 256 bytes. (That does not explain "requested_bytes: 3073 allocated_bytes: 4864" though.)